# How to show the unread notification on icon

Tags: android, notifications

I wonder how to show the unread count like msg program or email program

Dose anybody have some demo?

please help  thanks :)

Comment: What specific application do you want to know the count? Because each application has its own provider where you can retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a demo for it but I can tell you that these icons are [widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) and not normal app icons. I think the widget simply checks for emails periodically and changes the icon it shows depending on the number of unread mails.

Comment: how to add widget or view to notification ?

Comment: Ah, sorry you mean the icon in the notification bar?

Comment: Ah ok. So a counter cannot be set on the normal icon of an app as it is a normal icon file which is hardwired/defined in the manifest file. If you want an "icon" for the home screen which should show an unread count then you have to implement it as a widget which looks like a normal icon but can dynamically show the number of unread items.